# Why protractor cucumber is not able to locate step file with latest version of Cucumber in Protractor Cucumber framework

Tags: protractor, cucumber, cucumberjs

I'm working with protractor cucumber framework and since from the long time i observed is cucumber is not able to find the spec file in the project. I have used the cucumber latest version 6.0.3 it is not able to find the spec file but same code i have run using the cucumber 1.3.3.. can any body tell me what's the difference with this versions? is there any thing i need to update for 6.0.3

***Cucumber Dependency - 1.3.3***

```
"cucumber": {
      "version": "1.3.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cucumber/-/cucumber-1.3.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-Za+2Xy+T9y2teN8qterPFGCf7C8=",
      "requires": {
        "camel-case": "^3.0.0",
        "cli-table": "^0.3.1",
        "co": "^4.6.0",
        "colors": "^1.1.2",
        "commander": "^2.9.0",
        "duration": "^0.2.0",
        "figures": "1.7.0",
        "gherkin": "^4.1.0",
        "glob": "^7.0.0",
        "is-generator": "^1.0.2",
        "lodash": "^4.0.0",
        "stack-chain": "^1.3.5",
        "stacktrace-js": "^1.3.0"
      }
```

***Cucumber Dependency 6.0.3 Latest***

```
"cucumber": {
      "version": "6.0.3",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/cucumber/-/cucumber-6.0.3.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha512-FSx7xdAQfFjcxp/iRBAuCFSXp2iJP1tF2Q5k/a67YgHiYbnwsD9F+UNv9ZG90LFHNsNQhb+67AmVxHkp4JRDpg==",
      "dev": true,
      "requires": {
        "assertion-error-formatter": "^3.0.0",
        "bluebird": "^3.4.1",
        "cli-table3": "^0.5.1",
        "colors": "^1.1.2",
        "commander": "^3.0.1",
        "cucumber-expressions": "^8.0.1",
        "cucumber-tag-expressions": "^2.0.2",
        "duration": "^0.2.1",
        "escape-string-regexp": "^2.0.0",
        "figures": "^3.0.0",
        "gherkin": "5.0.0",
        "glob": "^7.1.3",
        "indent-string": "^4.0.0",
        "is-generator": "^1.0.2",
        "is-stream": "^2.0.0",
        "knuth-shuffle-seeded": "^1.0.6",
        "lodash": "^4.17.14",
        "mz": "^2.4.0",
        "progress": "^2.0.0",
        "resolve": "^1.3.3",
        "serialize-error": "^4.1.0",
        "stack-chain": "^2.0.0",
        "stacktrace-js": "^2.0.0",
        "string-argv": "^0.3.0",
        "title-case": "^2.1.1",
        "util-arity": "^1.0.2",
        "verror": "^1.9.0"
      }
```

***StepDef***

```
module.exports=function(){
    this.Given(/^Open the browser and Load the URL$/,async function(){
        await firstBrowser.get(properties.get("url1"));
        browser.logger.info("Title of the window is :"+await browser.getTitle());
        //screenshots.takesScreenshot("filename");
    });
    
    this.When(/^User entered the text in the search box$/,async function(){
        firstBrowser.sleep(3000);
        await page1.email().sendKeys(testData.Login.CM[0].Username);
        browser.sleep(3000);
        await page1.password().sendKeys(testData.Login.CM[0].Password);
    });
}
```

***Config File***

```
exports.config = {

//seleniumAddress: 'http://localhost:4444/wd/hub',
getPageTimeout: 60000,
allScriptsTimeout: 500000,
directConnect:true,

framework: 'custom',
// path relative to the current config file
frameworkPath: require.resolve('protractor-cucumber-framework'),
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome'
},
ignoreUncaughtExceptions:true,
// Spec patterns are relative to this directory.
specs: [
    'H:\\workspace\\Protractor_Cucumber\\src\\FeatureFiles\\Test.feature'
],

cucumberOpts: {
    require: 'H:\\workspace\\Protractor_Cucumber\\src\\StepDefFiles\\*.js',
    tags: false,
    profile: false,
    'no-source': true
},
 onPrepare: function () {
     browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false);
const {Given, Then, When, Before} = require('cucumber');

  }
};
```

i didn't used any cucumber hooks in my test scripts..
What makes them to work different, can some help in this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One reason is `Then/When/Given` usage change in `cucumber` 6.x, you can change few step functions to verify this.

For 1.x step function file looks like

```
module.exports = function () {

  this.Then(/^Then the response status is (.*)$/, function (status) {
    assert.equal(this.responseStatus, status)
  });
  this.When(//, ...)
}
```

For 6.x step function file looks like

```
const { Then, When } = require('cucumber');

Then(/^the response status is (.*)$/, function (status) {
  assert.equal(this.responseStatus, status)
});

When(//,...)
```

Another possible reason is need to upgrade `protractor-cucumber-framework` version which is compatible with the `cucumber@6.x`

Comment: i will check that

Comment: I have previously added `const { Then, When } = require('cucumber');` this in my config file,, after your comment i have added it to my step file also but same it is not able to find the step

Comment: Show  one your step file, also support file if you have for before/after like hook.  Cucumber 6.x has big diff than 1.x on syntax and usage.   I prefer you init an new project with Cucumber 6.x , then add simple feature and step file to see can work, then add support file if you need with Cucumber 6.x usage .  After  step and support files work well,  you can know how to migration your old project  from Cucumber 1.x to 6.x.

Comment: I have updated the Question with all details,,, check it once.

Comment: For 6.x step file no need `module.exports=function(){` , Please read the cucumber 6.x doc carefully https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-js/blob/HEAD/docs/support_files/step_definitions.md